# Why is $ |z|^2 = z z^* $?

Tags: complex-numbers, definition

I've been working with this identity but I never gave it much thought. Why is $ |z|^2 = z z^* $ ? Is this a definition or is there a formal proof?

Comment: what is the $z^*$ ?

Comment: Why do you aks this? Do you know what's the "usual" representation of a complex number as $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ ? Do you know what's the conjugate of a complex number? Then de the multiplication $\;z\overline z\;$ and that's all!

Comment: @Mher Safaryan It's the complex conjugate.

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm asking because I had no idea it's this simple. The identity was presented to me baldly along with a sloppy explanation to complex numbers back when I took my intro class. Unfortunately, not all educators are able to present mathematics in an accessible, intuitive way. That's a real skill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I take it that $z^*$ means the conjugate of $z$, then it follows from nothing more than algebra:

$$zz^* = (a+bi) \cdot (a-bi) = a^2 - abi + abi + b^2 = a^2 + b^2 = |z|^2$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $z=x+iy$, for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $zz^*=(x+iy)(x-iy)=x^2+y^2=|z|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no formal proof: it's a definition.

Looking at $z=x+yi$ and doing
$$
zz^*=(x+yi)(x-yi)=x^2+y^2
$$
shows that, when we interpret a complex number as a point in the Argand-Gauss plane, 
$|z|$ represents the distance of the point from the origin.